# Looking for examples using LDAP policy both for internal and external LDAP

Tags: apigee

Are there any examples of using the LDAP policy for both the internal Apigee LDAP or for external custom LDAP. Whenever I try, Apigee tells me "Invalid external ldap reference {name}", even when I'm trying to access the internal LDAP.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your LDAP policy?

Comment: That's just it, I don't know what to specify, going by the documentation [link](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/authenticating-users-and-getting-user-distinguished-names-ldap-policy) its not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create the LDAP resource.  Try using the following:

```
<LdapResource name="ldap1">
  <Connection>
    <Hosts> <!-- port is optional: defaults to 389 or 639 based of ssl -->
    <Host port="389">fl-console</Host>
    </Hosts>
    <SSLEnabled>false</SSLEnabled> <!-- optional, defaults to false -->
    <Version>3</Version> <!-- optional, defaults to 3-->
    <Authentication>simple</Authentication> <!-- optional, only simple supported now -->
    <ConnectionProvider>jndi</ConnectionProvider>
  </Connection>
  <ConnectPool enabled="true"> <!-- enables is optional, degaults to true -->
    <Timeout>30000</Timeout> <!-- optional, if not given, there is no timeout -->
    <Maxsize>50</Maxsize> <!-- optional, if not given there is no max connections -->
    <Prefsize>30</Prefsize> <!-- optional. if not given there is no pref size -->
    <Initsize></Initsize> <!-- optional, if not given it defaults to 1 -->
    <Protocol></Protocol> <!-- optional, defaults to 'ssl plain' -->
  </ConnectPool>
  <Admin>
    <DN>cn=admin,dc=apigee,dc=com</DN>
    <Password>secret</Password>
  </Admin>
</LdapResource>
```

Then POST this via MS API:.  You'll need to replace the ${variables} below, of course:

```
curl --basic -u "admin:secret" -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "${ldap_resource}" "http://${mg_host}/v1/organizations/${org}/environments/test/ldapresources"
```